# How to input hash (#) symbol to terminal?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, terminal, nano

I'm running Ubuntu Server as a virtual machine (using VirtualBox) on my mac.

Normally on the Mac, I'd press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to input the hash (#) sybmol.

However, if I do this in my Ubuntu Server's console, it gives me "Unrecognized Command" when inside nano.

How can I input this symbol? I need this to be able to add comments to my apache configuration file.

Thanks

Comment: Alt + 3? # is Shift + 3, isn't it?

Comment: What does normally happen if you press `alt-3`, e.g. in a text editor?  Does it work in `bash`; is the error just happening in `nano`? If you enter `read` in bash, press enter, then press `alt-3`, what happens?

Comment: Consider remapping the character to a different modifier key. In terminals, `alt` is also used as modifier for keyboard  shortcuts.

Comment: @Rob Only if your world ends at the US border. The British Mac keyboard layout uses `Shift-3` for the pound character `£`.

Comment: @Rob daniel is correct

Comment: @slhck if I press `alt-3` in bash it gives me `(arg: 3)`

Comment: @slhck and if I press `alt-3` in `read` it gives me `^[3`

Comment: @AlexCoplan It's the equivalent setting to *Use option as Meta key* in [Terminal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oTbkU.png). You need to remap the character to a different key, or change your Terminal's configuration.

Comment: Right... so if anyone could tell me how you do that with ubuntu server / virtualbox that would be great :)

Comment: You're running the server as command-line only, directly in Virtualbox?

Comment: @DanielBeck correct

Comment: @AlexCoplan Chances are that you need to press a different key, as the client VM interprets  your keystrokes in that case. Rob might be correct after all -- what happens when you press Shift-3 in Virtualbox Ubuntu?

Comment: @DanielBeck I get the pound symbol - I configured the ubuntu install to use British Mac keyboard layout on install

Comment: @AlexCoplan I think the Linux British keyboard layout [is a bit different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#United_Kingdom) from a Mac's. Try pressing \ right next to `Return`.

Comment: @DanielBeck - I'm just getting the \ symbol... The only key that I've found that is different so far is the \` symbol becomes < and `shift-\`` becomes >

Comment: @AlexCoplan Try using the right `alt` key, maybe it's `Alt-Gr` and changes things?

Comment: @DanielBeck that's it - thanks! - post as an answer and I'll upvote and accept

Comment: none of these worked for my so I just switched my keyboard to US!

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks! Saved my bacon (and #browns)

Comment: And if anyone finds this and via RSI has a goldtouch dual-win+mac-compatible keyboard, who is in the UK (one-row return, shift-3 character on the key is the hash character but when you do shift-3 you get £ and on macOS left-option-3 (with the win character on the key) is how you get #), right option-3 in your ubuntu VM (mine via parallels today) is how the hash gets inserted. phew!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Alt` is used as *Meta* on your system. That's why it behaves strangely in `nano` and `bash`.

---

On Ubuntu server (command-line only) with British keyboard layout, you need to press the right `alt` key to get the hash symbol `#`: Only the right `alt` is interpreted as `alt-gr` by your Linux system, and that's the modifier key required on non-Mac OS systems for the alternative characters on the keyboard.

Comment: Or as I found `ctrl` + `shift` + 3

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this as I'm doing my LPIC and using a MB Pro running CentOS in a VM.

Ended up being CTRL+\

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04 with UK keyboard, installed on a MacBook Pro. Unfortunately the right-side <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> only emits a superscript "2", not the hash, And the left-side <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> prints nothing.

Going to *System Preferences » Keyboard* I can see that my current keyboard is listed as: `English (UK, MacIntosh international)`.

Clicking on the little "keyboard" button at the bottom shows the position of all characters on each key. So for me the hash `#` is <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>, pipe and backslash). One of the previous posts said Alt but it was Ctrl

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal preferences, go to `Profiles` then `Keyboard`. Disable the `Use Option as Meta Key` option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me it's just the <kbd>\</kbd> key.

(Jessie, Virtualbox on El Capitan, UK keyboard)

Comment: Thank you, I think you are the only one to answer the actual question :-D.

Answer (score 0):

In late 2018, on the latest Macbook Pro with F keys as F keys, I need to type fn+option+3 to get `#` in terminal. Perhaps it's because in iTerm, under Profiles/Keys I have loaded preset "Natural Text Editing" (to allow travelling across words with option (alt)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what terminal the OP is using - probably the built-in terminal (Terminal.app), but in case anyone has this problem with iTerm2, here is what fixed it for me:

In iTerm2 Preferences > Keys > Navigation Shortcuts > "Shortcut to choose a split pane" was `opt+number`, so `opt+3` was mapped to focus the 3rd pane in your tab had been split into panes, but this was overriding the normal mapping of `opt+3` to `#`. I changed it to "No shortcut" and could then type hash symbols in iTerm.

I never had this problem before, but recently bought a new MacBook Pro M1 with MacOS Monterey, installed iTerm2 on it amongst other things, and then was was amazed to find that I couldn't type a hash symbol in the terminal - for example, for making comments in Python code or Bash scripts. I certainly didn't set it that way - so it must have been in the default setup of iTerm2. Why on earth the developers thought that was a good setting to have on by default, I don't know.